# EF6 does not roll back all changes within a transaction

Tags: transactions, entity-framework-6, rollback

My understanding is that unless transaction.Commit is called, all operations should be rolled back within the transaction scope. Why isn't Corleone bankrupt in the end?

```
using (var ctx = new BankDbContext()) {
using (var transaction = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction()) {
    try {
        var corleone = new BankAccount { Name = "Corleone", Balance = 100000M };
        ctx.Accounts.Add(corleone);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        Debug.Assert(corleone.Balance == 100000M);

        corleone.Balance += 100000M;
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        Debug.Assert(corleone.Balance == 200000M);

        throw new Exception("money laundering!");
        transaction.Commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        transaction.Rollback();
        Debug.Assert(!ctx.Accounts.Any(x => x.Name == "Corleone"));
    }
}}
```

Comment: It is committed *in* the database itself or does it just fail the Assert? Does the database *already* have an account with that name? Does it still commit if using a TransactionScope? What database?

Comment: Why? Because it doesn't exist. Maybe you should just tell what you expected to happen and what doesn't.